# Undo @Sql after each test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I have some junit tests where I want to pre-populate the DB with some data that actually makes sense for the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {


@Sql("test_insert.sql") 
@Test
public void testInsert(){
  ...performs some inserts...
}
@Sql("test_delete.sql") //makes inserts to the db so to delete them
@Test
public void testDelete(){
    ...
}
```

I noticed that junit executes the tests by reverse order, meaning that my testDelete will be executed first.

Test insert seems to fail for a "duplicate row constraint" and that happens because the test_delete.sql scripts actually adds that row.

Would it to be possible to rollback the operations made by the @Sql and the test itself so that one test does not influence the others?

Comment: The answer by @lealceldeiro is correct: you just need to make the tests `@Transactional`. I recommend you read the _Testing_ chapter of the Spring Reference Manual. This is all documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) on top of the JUnit test class. This will revert all changes made to the database after every test has ran.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional           //  <-- @Transactional added
public class MyTest {


@Sql("test_insert.sql") 
@Test
public void testInsert(){
  ...performs some inserts...
}
@Sql("test_delete.sql") //makes inserts to the db so to delete them
@Test
public void testDelete(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: If like me you land here and despite the `@Transactional` your `@Sql` scripts are not rolled back, one possibility is that you have played around with `@TestExecutionListeners`, if so, make sure the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class` is present.